# In how many days can Sachin alone complete the work given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Alok and Sachin agree to complete a piece of work in $20$ days?They also agree to forfeit double the amount of wages corresponding to the uncompleted part of work,if they fail.If Alok alone can complete the work in $40$ days and they lost $1$/$3$ of the pay of the total work.In how many days can Sachin alone complete the work?

options:

a) $60$ b) $24$ c) $36$ d) $30$

MyApproach:

Alok+Sachin=$20$ Days

If they fail,They  agree to forfeit double the amount of wages corresponding to the uncompleted part of work

If Alok alone can complete the work in $40$ days.

Therefore,Alok did 2.5% work in 1 day and given:(together)they did 5% work(20 days).

Therefore,Sachin do 2.5% work.

> I am confused how to use these equations to solve the problem.
>
> Can anyone guide me how to approach the problem correctly.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, please clarify it! Why  "and they lost 1/3 of the pay of the total work" is relevant? Does it mean that Alok has not completed the work during the 40 days, but 1/6 $((1/3)/2)$ of it has failed?

Answer (score 1):

Since they forfeit double the uncompleted amount, they completed $\dfrac56$ of the work in $20$ days, in which Alok completed $2.5*20 = 50\%$

So Sachin completed $\dfrac56 - \dfrac12 = \dfrac13$ of work in 20 days,

and can thus do the full work, alone, in $60$ days.